# Object detection in images meaning uses and comprehension

Tags: object, image-processing, grayscale, object-detection

Hello I am new in the world of image processing. I would like to know if object detection necessary means that the object is knnown and i must detect it ( example detecting faces in the image). Or it may be also just to detect any object in an image (like just detecting where are the objects in a grayscale image without mentioing the name or the kind of objects).

In one question, in image processing world can i make object detection without identifying the object?

Comment: The full name is *"Object Detection and Identification"*, which kind of implies you can have detection without identification.

Comment: So i can make object detection without identifying the object?

Comment: Yes, imagine a picture of a blue sea with red balls floating on it. You can detect that there are round objects without identifying them as balls or buoys or heads of swimmers.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what exactly you are planning to do, I would recommend looking into the following approaches:

1. Image segmentation divides the image up into parts so you can distinguish between different regions and also objects. [This link](https://de.mathworks.com/discovery/image-segmentation.html) explains it in more detail and shows different techniques for image segmentation.
2. Feature detection finds interesting points in an image, for examples pixel areas with high contrast. [Here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/feature-detection-and-extraction.html) you can find more on the topic.

Comment: My question that in image processing world can i do object detection without identifying the object?

Comment: Using the techniques I've mentioned, you are not identifying an object, just finding certain patterns in an image which can indicate that there is an object there. Both techniques don't tell you what kind of object it is.